# tail -f con clear

Tags: bash

Me gustaría que, al monitorizar un fichero con

`tail -f -n 5 fichero`,

hiciera un `clear` en cada actualización.

La idea es dejar una terminal que visualice únicamente las últimas líneas de un log, sin ver todas las versiones anteriores. ¿Es esto posible?

Lo que se me ocurre es algo así:

`while [[ 1 = 1  ]]; do sleep 1; clear; tail -n 5 ej3.txt; done`

Pero estaría mejor con algún parámetro de `tail`

Comment: Con el parámetro -n puedes limitar la cantidad de líneas.

Comment: Sí, efectivamente, completo la pregunta para tenerlo en cuenta. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Prueba con `watch tail -n5  ej3.txt`, creo que es justo lo que necesitas. En el caso que 2s sea mucho para ti, puedes usar `watch -n0.1 tail -n5 ej3.txt` y se actualizará cada 0.1s.

Comment: Sí, justo era eso... Intuía que en linux ya tenía que existir algo parecido, han pensado en todo ¡Gracias! Pégamelo en una respuesta y así dejamos la pregunta respondida :)

Comment: Ya está. Me alegra te haya servido @DavidJP

Comment: A pesar ed que ya te respondieron, en tu script podrías usar `whie : ; instrucciones`, es decir, los dos puntos : , porque no evaluan nada y siempre regresan true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para seguir los cambios del archivo usa el comando `watch`:

```
watch tail -n5  ej3.txt
```

`watch` por defecto mirará cada dos segundos los cambios de `tail -n5  ej3.txt` pero puedes modificar este tiempo usando `-n0.1`, donde `0.1` es el tiempo en segundos. Desafortunadamente menor tiempo que este no puedes lograr ya que solo se permite actualizar máximo 10 veces por segundo.

Con el tiempo de actualización el comando quedaría:

```
watch -n0.1 tail -n5 ej3.txt
```